# Specify the postion to call a function in a series of steps

Tags: python

I have a function **operations()** that performs a series of operations on a value. I am also performing an arbitrary operation on the value by passing in a function as a parameter. I am also specifying the position that the operation gets called, because that will affect the output. I am currently using an if statement at each position as shown in the code below, but is there a better tool for doing this? It's fine for this contrived example, but in my actual code there are a lot more steps, so it would end up being a lot of if statements.

```
def add1(val):
    return val + 1

def operations(value, position, func):  
    if position == 0:
        value = func(value)
    value *= 2
    if position == 1:
        value = func(value)
    value += 2
    if position == 2:
        value = func(value)
    value *= 3
    if position == 3:
        value = func(value)

    return value

operations(1, 0, add1) # returns 18
operations(1, 1, add1) # returns 15
operations(1, 2, add1) # returns 15
```

Comment: Do you always execute it consequentially? If so you could utilize generator.

Comment: How operations logically associated with position? I mean is `value *= 2` should be always after `position == 0` or always before `position == 1`?

Comment: @germn It doesn't really matter at this point, as long as it's consistent.

Comment: @david12345 answer I posted does what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer may depend of program logic, but here's code based on logic you shown:

```
import operator

def operations(value, position, func):  
    actions = {
        0: (operator.mul, 2),
        1: (operator.add, 2),
        2: (operator.mul, 3),
        3: (operator.add, 0),
    }

    for i, action in actions.items():
        if position == i:
            value = func(value)
        operation, val2 = action
        value = operation(value, val2)
    return value
```

You store position to actions in dict and use it in loop. See also [operator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html) module doc.

Answer (score 0):

You *probably* want a lookup for the functions you're working with so they can be retrieved arbitrarily.  The concept is not dissimilar to what you are already doing - passing a function as an argument to another function:

```
funcmap = {
  0: add1,
  1: add2,
  2: add3
}
```

Which would allow you to refer to a function by key and retrieve it at runtime:

```
value = funcmap[idx](value)
```